If the president pardons you for illegally entering the country, can you begin immigration paperwork immediately?
This is a hypothetical:
The president has a right to pardon any federal crime. If the president pardons you for illegally entering the country, can you begin immigration proceedings as having never entered the country illegally?

Just to be absolutely clear this question is alluding to the president providing a blanket pardon. I, the person asking, want to get away from the politics of it and merely handle the legality: whether or not the implications of a blanket pardon will be sufficient to begin immigration proceedings for undocumented immigrants and what that would look like. For these reasons, I'm asking the question as a hypothetical about one person.

Being pardoned for that doesn't mean that they are in the country legally now and eligible for the immigration process.

Why is this getting close-voted for lacking clarity? The question seems clear to me. Sure, the OP has misunderstood the distinction between illegal entry and immigration status, but that doesn't make the question unclear.

In order to be pardoned, you first have to be convicted.  But (I guess) the sentence for being convicted for illegally entering the country includes being deported.

@PeterM "In order to be pardoned, you first have to be convicted": not so, at least not under US federal law.

@phoog Not according to Wikipedia.  "The pardon power of the president applies only to convictions under federal law"

@PeterM Wikipedia is free; you get what you pay for.  See Ex parte Garland: "The power [of pardon] is unlimited, with the exception stated. It extends to every offence known to the law, and may be exercised at any time after its commission, either before legal proceedings are taken, or during their pendency, or after conviction and judgment." (It helps to look for statements supported by citations, such as the first sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_pardons_in_the_United_States#Definitions )

The Wikipedia page you link to should say "offences under federal law" rather than "convictions under federal law."  The source it cites says "The President can grant a pardon to a person who was convicted in a United States District Court, the Superior Court of the District of Columbia, or a military court-martial," which is true, but lacks the word "only."  The president can also grant -- and many presidents have granted -- pardons to people who have not yet been charged for crimes that were not even specifically identified, just "any crimes committed in connection with such-and-such."

"can you begin immigration proceedings as having never entered the country illegally?" What exactly do you mean by "begin immigration proceedings"? Nothing in your question indicates that the person qualifies to apply for any immigration benefits.

@PeterM Richard Nixon's is a notable exception to you contention but is probably not a good example. The pardons for all Vietnam draft dodgers has never been contested.

The Constitution's Naturalization Clause gives the power to Congress. The equivalent "pardon" occurs by a private bill being passed and signed by the President. This is extremely rare, 6 bills enacted in 9 years. Of course, this is the exact same process for broad immigration law changes.

@JBentley "Why is this getting close-voted for lacking clarity" - because the mere existence of this topic is inconvenient to people with certain ideological beliefs, so they want to suppress it, make it disappear, and if a question is uncomfortable to you, the "lacking clarity" is the easiest one to click if you want a question to disappear.

In order to be pardoned, you first have to be convicted -- Ford pardoned Nixon without Nixon being indicted.  Carter pardoned any Vietnam War draft dodgers, some of whom had been convicted, others only indicted, and many others not even that.  I believe Trump pardoned some of his friends before they were convicted but I may misremember.  HOWEVER, I don't think any of these have actually been put to the test in the court system, so we do not yet know whether such pardons have effect.  We only know that both parties are acting as if they think they probably do.

As I understand it, a pardon doesn't mean "You're innocent", it says "You did it, but because of Reasons or Circumstances you're forgiven". It exempts you from punishment but it very much doesn't wipe the slate clean.

In general, no.  The president's pardon excuses the recipient from trial, conviction, and punishment for the crime of illegal entry, but it does not grant the recipient a lawful immigration status.  Therefore, the recipient of the pardon remains subject to removal proceedings and possible removal from the US.
Consider the illegal aliens who didn't enter the country illegally, such as those who entered with a nonimmigrant visa but failed to depart when their nonimmigrant status ended.  These people are in a similar situation:  they have no criminal liability, but they lack immigration status and (absent other facts) lack any way of qualifying for it.

Yes, but having considered that it's trivial to begin immigration proceedings if you overstay your visa. You don't even have to leave the country to do it. I'm not sure this is a useful example. I married a woman here who entered with a J-1 visa. It is precisely because she was told DO NOT LEAVE THE COUNTRY that I extrapolate that out to other immigration proceedings. Merely not having entered illegally was material. The fact that she was here past her visa was immaterial. Had she have left, she would have been in queue to enter legally with a visa; when uscis would not otherwise care.

@EvanCarroll "it's trivial to begin immigration proceedings if you overstay your visa": you can always submit an application, but the vast majority of overstayers have no valid basis to become immigrants, so if they submit an application they're just throwing away their application fees of several hundred to a few thousand dollars.  For immediate relatives of a US citizen, including your wife, there is both a basis to apply and a benefit to not leaving the country.  For everyone else, the story is different.

Isn't a pardon, by definition, something that is post-conviction?

@PeterM no.  For a famous example, see Gerald Ford's pardon of Richard Nixon.  Nixon was never charged, let alone tried or convicted.

@phoog Fair point.  But I seriously doubt that the president would ever get involved in an immigration issue unless it was very high profile.  In which case the person in question would have a lot of other options.  However, one potential target would be Elon Musk who purportedly broke the conditions of his visa when he was a student.

@PeterM A president might not pardon single low profile individuals, but they might conceivably pardon all illegal entries

@PeterM it's true that such a pardon is unlikely (perhaps less so as a blanket pardon, as mentioned by Caleth, or for a high-profile individual, as you acknowledge).  But the premise of the question is that such a pardon has been granted (including, possibly, to everyone or to a famous individual) so, in the context of that assumption, we can examine the consequences of the pardon for further immigration applications, petitions, etc.

@EvanCarroll: "but having considered that it's trivial to begin immigration proceedings if you overstay your visa." Begin what "immigration proceedings"? On what basis? You are not in general eligible to apply for anything on the basis of being an overstayer. "I married a woman here who entered with a J-1 visa." Maybe you are talking about the case where you are a US citizen, in which case she has a basis to immigrate as the spouse of a US citizen. Most overstayers are not the spouse of a US citizen, and that's why your statement makes no sense.

@EvanCarroll: If you are asking specifically about whether a pardoned illegal entrant who is the spouse of a US citizen is eligible for Adjustment of Status inside the US, please say so in your question. The answer to that question is No, because Adjustment of Status requires that the person be admitted or paroled, and a pardon is not an admission or parole. What would allow them to do Adjustment of Status is parole-in-place, e.g. Keeping Families Together, but it was blocked

@user102008 I'm not asking about a spouse. I just don't understand how an answer that excludes them is relevant. When you say "entrant who is the spouse of a US citizen is eligible for Adjustment of Status inside the US" who made that rule a spouse of a US citizen is eligible for Adjustment of Status regardless of whether or not they're here legally? Is that statute? Or, is that a USCIS rule subject to whims of the Director? Where is that exemption? That, imho, should be part of the answer.

For example, let's say I was Director of the USCIS, and I wanted to extend the exemption for family, to "all nationals of the nations of the Americas" I think an answer would explain "Other than this group of exemptions mentioned in this statue or USCIS rule, you need to be here legally to start immigration proceedings. Outside of those exemptions, a pardon would not qualify you to begin immigration proceedings in the USA."

@EvanCarroll: Statute. You are confusing a few things. First of all, you generally need to be petitioned in one of several family-based or employment-based categories (8 USC 1153 and 8 USC 1151(b)), and wait until a visa number is available, to be eligible for an immigrant visa or Adjustment of Status. 8 USC 1255(a)(2). So the vast majority of "nationals of the Americas" do not have a path to immigrate (no matter through Adjustment of Status or Consular Processing) in the first place.

@EvanCarroll: In the case of people who are petitioned in one of the family-based or employment-based categories, and a visa number is available, but they are out of status, 8 USC 1255(c)(2) makes them ineligible for Adjustment of Status unless they are in the Immediate Relative category (spouse, parent, or unmarried under-21 child of US citizen), or other minor exceptions like 8 USC 1255(k) or 8 USC 1255(i) applies. This is not up to USCIS to change. Spouses of US citizens are in the Immediate Relative category, so 8 USC 1255(c)(2) does not apply, based on the text of the statute.

U.S.C. § 1325 makes it a crime to unlawfully enter the United States. It applies to people who do not enter with proper inspection at a port of entry or lie while going through inspection. A first offense is a misdemeanor punishable by a fine, up to six months in prison, or both.
U.S.C. § 1326 makes it a crime to unlawfully enter after having been deported.
A pardon for either of these would not be the equivalent of inspection (although of course the President could order the appropriate Department to do that, all the way up to granting citizenship).

The department responsible for inspection is the Department of Homeland Security.  The power of naturalization, on the other hand, rests with the Attorney General.

"inspection (although of course the President could order the appropriate Department to do that" It's not just inspection, but also admission or parole that is needed for Adjustment of Status for spouses of citizens; pardon is not admission or parole. And a recent attempt to grant parole to people who entered illegally was blocked. "all the way up to granting citizenship)." Only people who meet the legal requirements for naturalization can be granted naturalization.

@user102008: yes, the actions taken would be more complex than a simple raw statement, “You’re a citizen now”, but a pardon is already more than that as well.  In this hypothetical circumstances where the president feels compelled to pardon a 1325 violation, he can just as well feel compelled to make that person a US citizen by whatever means necessary.  Induction into the military would be one way to move the process along.

@user102008: although if it’s mere residency, the president could order the the CIA to apply 50 u.s.c. § 3508.

"he can just as well feel compelled to make that person a US citizen by whatever means necessary": the president does not have authority to do so. There are statutory requirements for naturalization; the president has no authority from congress to waive these requirements (nor does the attorney general). The fact that the pardon power is "more than" the power to naturalize someone is irrelevant -- the power of the pardon is granted to the president by the constitution. The power to naturalize is controlled by congress, and the executive must respect the conditions specified by congress.

@phoog: the president doesn’t have the power to declare someone a citizen, that doesn’t mean the President can’t make it happen.  The CIA answers to the president, and they can make up to a 100 people (plus immediate family) permanent residents.  PR’s in the military can apply for citizenship after DOD approves them.  Congress could of course do so in one go (direct to citizen by way of a bill, this has happened multiple times), but that doesn’t mean the president is powerless to work the system.
